# Inverse matrix of solution (of system ode's)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I prove that if we have the system of ode's of order $n$
$$\frac{d}{dt}X(t)=A(t)X(t), \text{with}\quad X(0)=I_n$$
where $X$ and $A$ are $n\times n$ matrices, then
$$\frac{d}{dt}X^{-1}(t)=-X(t)^{-1}A(t)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $X(t)$ is invertible for all $t$. Differentiate the equation $X(t)X(t)^{-1}=I_n$ to obtain

$$\left(\frac{d}{dt} X(t)\right) X(t)^{-1} + X(t) \frac{d}{dt} X(t)^{-1}=0$$

Rearranging and using the equation we get $$X(t)\frac{d}{dt} X(t)^{-1}=-\left(\frac{d}{dt} X(t)\right) X(t)^{-1}=-A(t)$$

Bringing $X(t)$ to the other side gives

$$\frac{d}{dt} X(t)^{-1}=-X(t)^{-1}A(t)$$